# Creating certificate with private key and extracting private key / alias name from certificate

Tags: certificate, digital-signature, private-key

I want to perform digital signature generation using private/public key cryptography. I have created the keystore and added the two alias (sender and receiver ) into the keystore.

While signing the data, I will be extracting the private key from keystore and sign the data. While verifying the data, I will be doing it from keystore. But I wanted to do digital sign using a certificate.

I have the following related questions:

1. How to create the certificate to include private key ?
2. During sign process, how to extract the same private key from the certificate ?
3. Can we do the creation/extraction of this using open-source such `keytool`, `openssl` etc.? Or do I need to get in touch with a certificate authority?

Comment: Usually you do not want the private key to be included in the certificate. The certificate essentially contains the *public* information others need to verify your signatures while the private key is... *private*.

Comment: For the case of Digital Signature, User needs to sign his content using privateKey. but we are not delivering privatekey to him explicitly, we do give the certificate. any idea how certificate can sign the content with-out privateKey ..?

Comment: *but we are not delivering privatekey to him explicitly* - that's unfortunate because he needs it. *any idea how certificate can sign the content with-out privateKey* - signing by definition uses the private key and verification uses the public one. If the private could easily be retrieved from the public one, the whole concept would be meaningless.

Comment: Generally the user creates the public/private key pair and uses that to send a *certificate request* to the signing party (which seems to be you). After verification that the certificate request came from the right party you create the certificate (using the information from you, the information in the request and a signature from *your* signing key) and send it back to the user. And yes, `openssl certreq` exists and may be used.